# What is the reason for `TX-dropped` in tespmd application?

Tags: dpdk

We are seeing lot of *TX-dropped* in our testpmd application during testing. We do not see any tx or rx error counters in *xstats*  i.e. *show port xstats <>". Like to know what is the reason for this Tx-Drop. Is it some limitation of testpmd application (s/w issue) or NIC/PCI or other h/w issue?

```
  ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 0  ----------------------
  RX-packets: 714397769      RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 714397769
  TX-packets: 362002429      TX-dropped: 388009969     TX-total: 750012398
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ---------------------- Forward statistics for port 1  ----------------------
  RX-packets: 750012398      RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 750012398
  TX-packets: 714397769      TX-dropped: 0             TX-total: 714397769
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  +++++++++++++++ Accumulated forward statistics for all ports+++++++++++++++
  RX-packets: 1464410167     RX-dropped: 0             RX-total: 1464410167
  TX-packets: 1076400198     TX-dropped: 388009969     TX-total: 1464410167
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Those Tx-Drop are per queue

```
  ------- Forward Stats for RX Port= 0/Queue= 3 -> TX Port= 1/Queue= 3 -------
  RX-packets: 163410610      TX-packets: 65937099       TX-dropped: 97473511

  ------- Forward Stats for RX Port= 1/Queue= 3 -> TX Port= 0/Queue= 3 -------
  RX-packets: 163158385      TX-packets: 65966669       TX-dropped: 97191716

  ------- Forward Stats for RX Port= 0/Queue= 4 -> TX Port= 1/Queue= 4 -------
  RX-packets: 163614447      TX-packets: 65939904       TX-dropped: 97674543

  ------- Forward Stats for RX Port= 1/Queue= 4 -> TX Port= 0/Queue= 4 -------
  RX-packets: 163276445      TX-packets: 65974629       TX-dropped: 97301816

  ------- Forward Stats for RX Port= 0/Queue= 5 -> TX Port= 1/Queue= 5 -------
  RX-packets: 163174658      TX-packets: 65925615       TX-dropped: 97249043
```

Regards,
Nilanjan

Comment: share the cmdline used for testpmd, nic used for the same, and the other end of DPDK port connected to (pktgen, Linux, ixia)?

Comment: We are using Mellanox NIC. Using Trex for packet generation. Using testpmd like `/testpmd -l16-31 -w 0000:41:00.0 -w 0000:41:00.1 -- -i --burst=64 --rxd=512--txd=512 --rxq=4 --txq=4 --nb-cores=8 --numa` . We are tuning our system for high traffic. 

Like to know the definition of `TX-dropped` counter seen in testpdm. Can this be mapped with one of the standard `xstats` counter? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: how is traffic generated to DPDK ports (Linux, dpdk-pktgen or ixia)? reason for asking is you are having TX-DROP, which means the receiver is getting congested.

Comment: Do you mean some back pressure from NIC? Will there be any h/w counter we should look corresponding for that? 
TREX is also using DPDK from a multi core system. I do not suspect TREX system, since same we used for testing other system with higher throughput already.

Comment: You have not shared your TREX configuration to analyze so I have to make educated guess

Answer (score 0):

here are the official numbers for Mellanox NIC `http://fast.dpdk.org/doc/perf/DPDK_20_02_Mellanox_NIC_performance_report.pdf`. This will give reference to what NIC is able to achieve on fully configured system for various packet sizes. It also includes the configuration and setup parameters.

A couple of pointers which affects your performance.

1. 1GB vs 2MB huge page
2. since you are using NUMA 1 your huge pages should be from NUMA via `socket-mem & socket-limit`
3. BIOS and power governed settings.
4. Since it is AMD is it EPYC gen 1 or gen2. If gen-1 your access to memory is via NUMA-0 for NUMA-1
5. congestion in the receiver (TREX), if single CPU core is used for fetching packets from both DPDK interface.
6. Mismatch in advertised and current assigned link speeds `sudo lspci -vvs [PCIe B:D:F] | egrep "LnkCap|LnkSta"`
7. Firmware mismatch `lshw -c network | grep -i firm`

these are some of the causes for TX drop for any given NIC.

Comment: Thanks Vipin. Since we are using AMD EPYC2, so referring `DPDK_19_08_Mellanox_NIC_AMD_performance_report.pdf` . The document you mentioned is for Intel I think. Is there DPDK 20.02 report there for AMD EPYC2? 

As we observed, when we hit PCI memory (pcie 4), we see TX-Drop. So should be related to PCI bandwidth I think. Is there any report of DPDK perf test with PCI bandwidth optimisation?

Comment: Nilanjan, if you check the documentation machine configuration is for `Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8168 CPU @ 2.70GHz`. these values are achievable. Have you tried putting the card in different NUMA and test?

Comment: have you tried to ping your huge page with `--socket-mem=1,1024 --socket-limit=1,2048` for NUMA-1. If you indeed think it is PCIe-4 issue, have tried moving the card to another slot or NUMA?

Comment: @Nilanjan are there any updates on running on the application with shared configuration?